# What are the most promising areas where quantum computers could advance quantum chemistry in the next 3-5 years?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, quantum-computing

[A very similar question was asked about 4 years ago](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/404/97), but this is a fast moving field, so I think it warrants reexamining.

What are the most promising areas where quantum computers could advance quantum chemistry in the next 3-5 years?

Note: This question could potentially be very broad, but I'm specifically interested in the impact on quantum chemistry and the type of problems currently solved with density functional theory or *ab initio* methods.

Comment: Feel free to ping me if you don't get an answer when there's 24 hours remaining for the bounty! I'll try my best to help.

Comment: A promising field is to model a whole protein into the framework of quantum mechanics. These could lead to create personalized medicines to rare illnesses.